# How to override default Magento (1.9.2.4) controller /customer/account/create with controller in my module?

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, registration

I want to create a new controller for the registration page. How can I do this in my own controller? The allegedly duplicate question is actually not about overriding a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/etc/modules/Override_Customer.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Override_Customer>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Override_Customer>
  </modules>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Override/Customer/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Override_Customer>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Override_Customer>
  </modules>
   <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <override_customer before="Mage_Customer">override_customer</override_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

> app/code/local/Override/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php

```
<?php
require_once "Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php";  
class Override_Customer_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this solves it. I Already did it like that in the meanwhile, missed a part that you wrote, so, thanks.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help.. :)