# How can I save the customer's login & registration form data in my log?

Tags: magento-1.9, log, login-register

I want to add the form data in log files when the customer submits the login/registration form on my Magento 1 store. How can I do it using `login.phmtl` and `register.phtml` template files?

I am using **Magento ver. `1.9.4.4`**

I tried using the below method but not working.

```
<?php
    Mage::log(print_r($formData, 1), null, 'logfile.log',true);
?>
```

How do I fetch the data of form i.e. Customer's **name**, **email** & **password** in the `$formData` variable?

I just want to know that is the form is submitted successfully or not.

As the login and signup are not working on my Magento 1.9 store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easier is to override the customer controller, you also just check for an ID instead of a log. check if the user gets an entity_id after save, which you can also find in this controller. Templates don't work well for this.

Here is an explanation on how to override the controller: [How to override default Magento (1.9.2.4) controller /customer/account/create with controller in my module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/198565/how-to-override-default-magento-1-9-2-4-controller-customer-account-create-wi)

Don't forget to disable this when you're done with debugging, this data is sensitive.

Comment: Thanks @FROSIT You saved my time... Thank you very much!